# How to make custom UITableViewCell height changed when user select or deselect it?

Tags: swift, uitableview

In my project I have a `UITableView` that every time user tap any cell, the cell's height increased with showing some long text inside cell and when tap it again or tap another cell, the cell's height decreased and showing some short text.(with some animation)

this is my custom cell code:

```swift
    class SomeCustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    static let identifier = "SomeCustomCellId"

    var shortDescLabel: AvatarLabel!
    var longDescLabel: AvatarLabel!
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        backgroundColor = selected ? UIColor.lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.5) : .clear
        
        if selected {
            didSelected()
        } else {
            deSelected()
        }
    }
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        selectionStyle = .none
        
        shortDescLabel = AvatarLabel()
        shortDescLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(shortDescLabel)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            shortDescLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            shortDescLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 20),
            shortDescLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
            shortDescLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -10)
        ])
        
        longDescLabel = AvatarLabel()
        longDescLabel.alpha = 0.0
        longDescLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        longdateLabel.isHidden = true
        longDescLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(longDescLabel)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            longDescLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            longDescLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 20),
            longDescLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            longDescLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -10)
        ])
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func didSelected() {
        longDescLabel.isHidden      = false
        shortDescLabel.isHidden     = true
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) { [weak self] in
            
            self?.shortDescLabel.alpha  = 0.0
            self?.longDescLabel.alpha   = 1.0
        }
    }
    
    func deSelected() {
        
        longDescLabel.isHidden      = true
        shortDescLabel.isHidden     = false

        backgroundColor = .clear
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) { [weak self] in
            self?.shortDescLabel.alpha  = 1.0
            self?.longDescLabel.alpha   = 0.0
        }
    }
    
    func setSomeCustomCell(_ someModel: SomeModel) {
        
        shortDescLabel.text = someModel.shortText
        longDescLabel.text  = someModel.longText
    }
    }
```

and this is my `UITableView` code:

```swift
    extension someViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            
            if someModels.count == 0 {
                tableView.setEmptyView()
            } else {
                tableView.restore()
            }
            
            return someModels.count
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: SomeCustomCell.identifier) as? SomeCustomCell else {
                return SomeCustomCell()
            }
            let item = someModels[indexPath.row]
            cell. setSomeCustomCell(item)
            
            return cell
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            
            if selectedCellIndexPath == indexPath {
                self.selectedCellIndexPath = nil
                guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? SomeCustomCell else { return }
                cell.deSelected()
            } else {
                self.selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath
            }
    
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.endUpdates()
            if selectedCellIndexPath != nil {
                // This ensures, that the cell is fully visible once expanded
                tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .none, animated: true)
            }
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            if selectedCellIndexPath == indexPath {
                return 140
            }
            return 90
        }
        }
```

but there is a problem, when user tap on some cell and tap it again(cell first going large and then become small) and scroll down(the selected cell now is not showing on screen anymore) and then scroll up to see that cell, the cell's height is small but the long data is showing (instead of showing short data). why this is happening and how to solve this problem?

Comment: you can try with `selectedRow` instead if `selectedCellIndexPath`. And the value of `selectedRow` will be `indexPath.row`. Hope this will help.

Comment: you mean instead of store indexPath, store the cell? I really don't understand, could you please explain more?

Comment: Not the cell. just store the `indexPath.row` value. And in the heightForRowAt method you can check via this code `selectedRow == indexPath.row`

Comment: yes I can do this, but it is not solving my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling your own func to change the "selected / not-selected" appearance of a cell does ***NOT*** inform the table view of the change.

With your current code, when you tap a second time on a cell you are telling the cell to change its appearance, but as far as the table view knows, that cell *is still selected*.

So, when you scroll down and then back up, the table view is "re-selecting" the row automatically.

Change your `didSelectRowAt` to this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if selectedCellIndexPath == indexPath {
        self.selectedCellIndexPath = nil
        // tell the table view to deselect the row!
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        //guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? SomeCustomCell else { return }
        //cell.deSelected()
    } else {
        self.selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath
    }
    
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
    if selectedCellIndexPath != nil {
        // This ensures, that the cell is fully visible once expanded
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .none, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: do you know why the tableView does not informed? I think the reason of the problem must be beginUpdates and endUpdates.

Comment: @behrad - It's not that the table view is not informed... If you create a simple test table view, you will see that tapping on a selected cell does **not** deselect it. The cell becomes deselected when you tap on (select) a *different* cell. Your code was forcing the *appearance* of deselecting the cell, without actually deselecting it.

Comment: The beginUpdates() / endUpdates() has nothing to do with the issue.